# Issue with CSS and border-radius

Tags: html, scroll, css

I need some help with a css 3 issue...

Problem is when I defined a scrollBox with boder-radius and then I scroll to the bottom, there is a clipping issue with the border.
There is no problem if the content div is defined with static position, but I need it to be relative for a translation effect.

You can try the following code to see what I mean :

```
<html>

<body>
    <div class="scrollBox" style="width:50%;height:100px;background:grey;border-radius:10px">
        <div class="content" style="height:100%;overflow:scroll">
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
            <div>Item</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope there is actually a solution for my problem.
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried adding a `padding`? Also: are you sure you shouldn't use a list and list items (`li`) for what you are trying to display?

Answer (score 2):

Add a little horizontal padding: `.content { padding:0 10px;`}

I think `border-radius` just rounds the corners of the background color, it doesn't actually change the shape/clip the corners of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Border radius will actually clip the content, not only the background color. All you need is `overflow: hidden;` for container block `.scrollBox`